# prevent single tables from using the cache

Tags: java, caching, jpa, openjpa

We are using OpenJPA 2.2.x and have a couple of tables that are filled outside our application (by an Asterisk plugin).

This forces us to disable OpenJPA caching in general. That might have a bad effect and actually caching can be quite handy for performance and tuning later.
After all I think it is also a rather bad design decision to disable the caching completely just because of a single feature.

Is there a way to force OpenJPA to always read certain tables from the database instead of using the cache?

Or are there other popular patterns to resolve this?

Thanks!
Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the JPA 2.0 spec.... it should outline exactly what you're looking for.

The short story is that you could set `<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>` in your p.xml and use the `@javax.persistence.Cachable` annotation in cacheable Entities.

Hope this helps.

Rick